# SVR object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to use the sklearn SVR method but when I write the `SVR()` function it throws an error. It says `SVR is not a callable`.

This is how I call it

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
```

Here's the code where I get the error

```
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poli = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree = 2)
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
```

And this is the error I get:

> error in prediccion(fechas, precios, x)
>
> ```
> 24     svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
> 25 
> 26     svr_lin(fechas, precios) <----
> 27     svr_poli(fechas, precios)
> 28     svr_rbf(fechas, precios)
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'SVR' object is not callable

I also tried with other methods like SVC and the same error comes out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function `fit()` on SVR objects like for example:

```
svr_lin.fit(fechas, precios)
```

Read more [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.fit)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fit() method

```
svr_lin.fit(fechas, precios)
```

More info [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html)